# Error : ImportError: libclntsh.so.10.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 on Centos 6

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, centos, cx-oracle

I 've try to install Oracle xe 10g (32bit) On my Centos 6 64 bit.
Alhamdulillah Oracle xe run well. But when itry to install cx_Oracle to connect my python2.7 with this oracle. I got

```
ImportError: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and then i set my Oracle Home to

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
```

and

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Now i got error:

```
ImportError: libclntsh.so.10.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

CMIIW , This error caused by this Oracle-xe 10g with 32 installed on my Centos 6 64. I can't finde Oracle-xe 10g 64 version so i just install this version.

Thank you..

Comment: Just For information i used cx_Oracle.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle. Should i uninstalled it and cange with cx_Oracle.i386 ?